# online creating and accessing oracle and db2 database

Tags: oracle, db2

I have to create and access oracle and db2 database. I don't have both database on my local system. Somebody knows there is any site which provides to create and access those database.
I have to check my desktop application with both database so please help me. I had googled a lot but didn't find anything.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should develop your application locally, since it's definitely free…

Otherwise take a look at this:

[Oracle Application Express](http://apex.oracle.com)

or on Amazons servers:
[Amazon AWS Free](http://aws.amazon.com/free/)

Comment: There's also an [express version for DB2](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express/download.html).  You have to create an IBM website account, but that's free as well.

Comment: @septi how do I connect to the database on APEX?